# HTML encoding in SQL

Tags: html, sql, character-encoding

I have a requirement where I have to encode/decode a string having special characters or symbols in SQL to its HTML equivalent values. 
Have tried with utl_i18n.escape_reference or utl_i18n.unescape_reference but it does not work for all characters or sysmbols. Below is such example:

```
select utl_i18n.escape_reference('REGIONS BANK Ó MORTGAGE Û') from dual;
```

Expected Output---- `REGIONS BANK &Oacute; MORTGAGE &Ucirc;`
Output Got --- `REGIONS BANK Ó MORTGAGE Û`

The unescape is working if i pass the text as

```
REGIONS BANK &Oacute; MORTGAGE &Ucirc;
```

Are there any other utilities that I can use for the same?

Comment: What database platform & version?  Looks like it might be oracle.  Maybe use UTL_URL.escape instead?  `SELECT UTL_URL.escape('REGIONS BANK Ó MORTGAGE Û') as val FROM DUAL`

Answer (score 0):

You asked:
**Are there any other utilities that I can use for the same?**
*Answer:* UTL_URL with it's escape and unescape functions.

[Reference: Oracle DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_url.htm#ARPLS073)

`UTL_URL.escape` provides output of `REGIONS%20BANK%20%D3%20MORTGAGE%20%DB` instead of what you have.

If you unescape the resulting value; you get your original `REGIONS BANK Ó MORTGAGE Û` back.

This function appears to be URL safe which I think is what you're after.

Your example keeps the space which I don't think is URL safe.

Example Script:

```
SELECT UTL_URL.escape('REGIONS BANK Ó MORTGAGE Û') as val FROM DUAL
UNION ALL 
SELECT UTL_URL.unescape('REGIONS%20BANK%20%D3%20MORTGAGE%20%DB') as val FROM DUAL;
```

Gives us the expected/desired results:

```
REGIONS%20BANK%20%D3%20MORTGAGE%20%DB
REGIONS BANK Ó MORTGAGE Û
```